# Apache slider LLAP container fails to start

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

I am trying to launch an LLAP container and I see the following error in the container log

```
 Log Type: slider-agent.out

Log Upload Time: Fri Nov 30 02:01:10 -0800 2018

Log Length: 783

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./infra/agent/slider-agent/agent/main.py", line 34, in <module>
    from Controller import Controller
  File "/var/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1543348222965_5967/filecache/70/slider-agent.tar.gz/slider-agent/agent/Controller.py", line 38, in <module>
    from NetUtil import NetUtil
  File "/var/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1543348222965_5967/filecache/70/slider-agent.tar.gz/slider-agent/agent/NetUtil.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ssl import SSLError
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 97, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_method
```

And I see the following on the AM diagnostics info -

```
Unstable Application Instance : - failed with component LLAP failed 'recently' 6 times (6 in startup); threshold is 5 - last failure: Failure container_e47_1543348222965_5967_01_000007 on host .....
```

Any help? I am using apache slider slider-0.91.0

Comment: Did you solve this problem, i got same problem with u